# How to sort data within a "list" using ORDER function in R

Tags: r, list, sorting

I have created a list of data as shown below

```
> sites
[[1]]
   ANLL_ID      lat     long      X       Y Depth_m       
15      B3 23.78038 90.63857 259364 2631912    94.2 
16      B4 23.78038 90.63857 259364 2631912    29.9 
17      B5 23.78038 90.63857 259364 2631912    47.1 
18      B6 23.78038 90.63857 259364 2631912    51.5 
19      B7 23.78038 90.63857 259364 2631912     6.0 
20      B8 23.78038 90.63857 259364 2631912    10.2 
21      B9 23.78038 90.63857 259364 2631912    25.6 


[[2]]
   ANLL_ID   lat   long      X       Y Depth_m                    
22      C1 23.79 90.611 256572 2633025      15 
23      C2 23.79 90.611 256572 2633025       8  
24      C3 23.79 90.611 256572 2633025      10  
25      C4 23.79 90.611 256572 2633025      94  
26      C5 23.79 90.611 256572 2633025      53  

... ...
```

If I want to order/sort (keeping all variables) the long list using sapply according to 'Depth_m' as:

```
sites.srt<- lapply(1:length(sites),
                   function(i) sites[order(sites[[i]]$Depth_m),])
```

But R throws an error-

```
Error in sites[order(sites[[i]]$Depth_m), ] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
```

I know it's happening because the data is as LIST, NOT as a dataframe. I can turn it into a dataframe. But keeping the data as a list makes it easier for me to do further processing. Is there any way to sort within the lists- [[1]], [[2]], ... ... [[15]]?

Comment: Do you want to sort / order each data frame w/i their position in the list, or do you want to reshuffle the order of these data frames in the list? If the latter, how is this supposed to happen based on `Depth_m`, given that there are many different values for this variable w/i each data frame? Can you provide an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: I want it reshuffle within each list e.g. for [[1]], the data should be arranged according to the Depth_m i.e. 6, 10.2, 25.6 and so on. Using ORDER will rearrange all the variables based on one.

Comment: For your approach to work, you need `function(i) sites[[i]][order(sites[[i]]$Depth_m),])`, but obviously James approach is much better, i.e. loop on the list items directly rather than the indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly

```
lapply(sites, function(x) x[order(x$Depth_m),])
```

will give you what you want.

Comment: +1 - also plyr's `arrange` function can make for a quite concise `lapply(sites, arrange, Depth_m)`